# editing nmap2db.pl (changing database update statements)

Tags: php, mysql, database, perl

I am building a database that contains information about hosts on my network. I present this data on a website generated by PHPMaker. (http://www.hkvstore.com/phpmaker/)

The purpose of this project is to build an IP address management system.

It is important that we keep historic data of any record in the DB. If we manually change a record on the PHPMaker built site we can write the old record data to another table. The code used to make this happen looks like this. (Might not be totally relevant but I put it here so you can get an idea about what the data looks like)

```
$sInsertSql = "INSERT INTO IPHistoric (ip, status, hostname, last_scanned, mac, ManualHost, Reservation) 
    VALUES ('" . $rsold['ip'] . "', '" . $rsold['status'] . "', '" . $rsold['hostname'] . "', '" . $rsold['last_scanned'] . "', '" . $rsold['mac'] . "', '" . $rsold['ManualHost'] . "', '". $rsold['Reservation'] . "')";
```

Now, I also populate the data with a perl script called nmap2db.pl ( http://search.cpan.org/~apersaud/Nmap-Parser-1.2/tools/nmap2db.pl ) which makes it very easy to do an nmap scan of a subnet and populate that data into a table.

What I need:

I need the perl script save any old data to the IPHistoric table instead of just overwriting every time. 
I have done some slight modifications to the script (removed some fields from the db schema)

Pastebin of the full script:
http://pastebin.com/V3AwcBVR

It looks like lines 92 through 95 are where the magic happens.

```
$S{INSERT_HOST}
    = qq{REPLACE INTO }
    . $G{TABLE}
    . qq{ (ip, mac, status, hostname) VALUES (?,?,?,?)};
```

So anyway... I don't know Perl and I'm not very good at SQL. Is it clear what I am trying to acheive? Is it possible to edit this script to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

This looks pretty straightforward.

However, the way your database is structured right now, the primary key is the IP address.

```
#Schema for table, simple for now
$S{CREATE_TABLE} = qq{  CREATE TABLE } . $G{TABLE} . qq{ (
  ip              VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  mac             VARCHAR(17) ,
  status          VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT 'Down',
  hostname        VARCHAR(50),
  last_scanned    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  };
```

This schema will only allow a single record for each IP address, which means if you update the existing record with new data, the old data is discarded.

You can prevent this by removing the primary key constraint from the table schema for IP address and instead putting it on, say, mac address.  Since mac addresses are statistically unique, you shouldn't ever get duplicates.  If you have a single mac address claiming to own multiple IP addresses, you might want to know about that anyway.

With the primary key constraint removed from the ip column, you can now have multiple records for the same IP address.  The trick is to find out which one is current.  You could do this with timestamps.  Create two extra columns in your database and call them something like CREATE_TIME and END_TIME.

Each time a record is inserted in the database, insert the current timestamp into CREATE_TIME.  If a record for that ip already exists, insert a current timestamp into END_TIME and then create a new record.  That way you'll know how long each IP record was assigned based on the CREATE_TIME and END_TIME timestamps.

Since END_TIME is only written when the record is changed, you can get the current set of IP records by doing something like:

```
    select * from TABLE where END_TIME is NULL;
```

Hope that made sense.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I like my way better :) Here's why: MAC address can't be primary because there won't always be one... but mostly I don't have a good way to display the data for an entire ip range.... Maybe I could write a select statement matching on the ip range and finding the most current record. Hmm. I will think about it and talk this plan over with my DBA guy. I like to have options and I still want to find a way to do what I asked originally.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now.  Somehow I missed that you want a separate table.

Comment: Then I would create another function at line 98 in your script, right above $np->callback( \&insert_host); and call a new function called insert_historic.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, using the "historic table" theme:

```
use vars qw(%S %G %H);

$H{TABLE} ||='IPHistoric';

$S{INSERT_HISTORIC}
    = qq{INSERT INTO }
    . $H{TABLE}
    . qq{ (ip, status, hostname, last_scanned, mac, ManualHost, Reservation) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)};

my $hist_ins = eval { $dbh->prepare_cached( $S{INSERT_HISTORIC} ) };
my $np = new Nmap::Parser;
$np->callback( \&insert_historic );

sub insert_historic {
    my $host = shift;
    my $os   = $host->os_sig();

    #ip, mac, status, hostname
    my @input_values = (
        $host->rsold['ip'],
        $host->rsold['status'],
        $host->rsold['hostname'],
        $host->rsold['last_scanned'],
        $host->rsold['mac'],
        $host->rsold['ManualHost'],
        $host->rsold['Reservation']
    );

    my $rv
        = $hist_ins->execute(@input_values) ? "ok" : "OOPS! - " . DBI->errstr;

    printf( "\t..> %-15s : (%4s) : %-s\n", $host->addr, $host->status, $rv );
}
```

That's probably got a couple of typos in it but you get the idea.  Basically, once you have your $rsold variables set, you can call the insert_historic sub and save all of those values to the IPHistoric table.

The code below won't run standalone, because it relies on a lot of other things set up in the code you linked.  But you should be able to copy/pase the $S{INSERT_HISTORIC} section right below the ${INSERT_HOST} section, and the insert_historic sub would go right below your insert_host sub.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

we added the INSERT_HISTORY part.

```
$S{INSERT_HISTORY}
=   qq{ INSERT_INTO IPHistoric }
    . qq{ ip, status, hostname, last_scanned, mac, ManualHost, Reservation }
  . qq { SELECT ip, status, hostname, last_scanned, mac, ManualHost, Reservation FROM }
    . $G{TABLE}
    . qq { WHERE ip = ? AND ( mac <> ? OR hostname <> ? ) };

$S{UPDATE_HOST}
= qq{UPDATE }
  . $G{TABLE}
  . qq { SET mac = ? , status = ?, hostname = ?, last_scanned = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP }
```